# Http session synchronization between webview and java http client in Android

Tags: android, http, httpclient, android-webview, httprequest

I am developing hybrid application by using webview and native both. I am using ajax post method in my webview and also using post method via HttpClient  on my default android code.
But even if i go to same server my session id's doesn't match with each other.

Is there any way to make http request within same session in my application?
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this issue:

```
public void syncSession(final Context ctx){

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){

            //Products will be stated in memory 
            ProductManager pm = ProductManager.getInstance();

            //              HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpget = new HttpPost(UrlConstants.SERVICE_URL_SYNC);
            HttpResponse response;
            String result = null;
            try {
                response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
                //write db to 

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 



            List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();

            if (! cookies.isEmpty()){

                CookieSyncManager.createInstance(ctx);
                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

                //sync all the cookies in the httpclient with the webview by generating cookie string
                for (Cookie cookie : cookies){

                    Cookie sessionInfo = cookie;

                    String cookieString = sessionInfo.getName() + "=" + sessionInfo.getValue() + "; domain=" + sessionInfo.getDomain();
                    cookieManager.setCookie(UrlConstants.SERVICE_PRE_URL, cookieString);
                    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
                }
            }

        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: could you please tell me where you insert this function and how you use it ?? thanks.

Comment: what is httpget used for ?