# Xamarin.Android: How Can I Pass WebView Login Creds Into HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, authentication, webview, xamarin.android, httprequest

I am trying to pass login creds from a `WebView` into an `HttpWebRequest` but not having any luck getting an authenticated response.  I am able to successfully make the request, but the response is acting like I haven't logged in.  My app has 5 `WebViews` contained within `Fragment` s and I'm logged in on all of them.  I've tried using the `CookieSyncManager` but it's deprecated and `.Sync()` didn't work.  I've tried a lot of different ways of passing the cookies into the `HttpRequest` with no success and many hours spent.

One would think this is a simple request; user has logged in within the app; they should be authenticated for all requests.  Here's the closest that I've gotten, but the response string is still not the same as through my authenticated `WebView` :

This attempt parses each `Cookie` into a string and adds it

```
    public string _cookieString { get; set; }

    private class ExtWebViewClient : WebViewClient
    {
        TheFragment5 _fm5 = new TheFragment5();

        public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
        {
            var cookieHeader = Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.GetCookie(url);
            var cookiePairs = cookieHeader.Split('&');
            _fm5._cookieString = "";

            foreach (var cookiePair in cookiePairs)
            {
                var cookiePieces = cookiePair.Split('=');
                if (cookiePieces[0].Contains(":"))
                    cookiePieces[0] = cookiePieces[0].Substring(0, cookiePieces[0].IndexOf(":"));
                cookies.Add(new Cookie
                {
                    Name = cookiePieces[0],
                    Value = cookiePieces[1]
                });
            }

            foreach (Cookie c in cookies)
            {
                if (_fm5._cookieString == "")
                {
                    _fm5._cookieString = c.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    _fm5._cookieString += c.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've also tried just doing:

```
_fm5._cookieString = cookieHeader.ToString();
```

but neither of those attempts is working when I add the cookie string into my `HttpRequest` :

```
        public async void GetNotificationText(string url)
        {
            //var _cmhc = _cookieMan.HasCookies;
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {

                _notificationHttpRequestInProgress = true;

                try
                {
                    var _ctxxx = Android.App.Application.Context;

                    //URL _url2 = new URL("https://bitchute.com/notifications/");
                    //HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)_url2.OpenConnection();

                    //conn.ReadTimeout = 10000 /* milliseconds */;
                    //conn.ConnectTimeout = 15000 /* milliseconds */;
                    ////conn.SetRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
                    //conn.Connect();

                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                    Uri uri = new Uri(url);

                    var _req = request;
                    var _uriii = uri;
                    var _cookiesss = _fm5._cookieString;

                    _cookieCon.SetCookies(uri, _cookiesss);

                    request.CookieContainer = _cookieCon;
                    //request.CookieContainer.SetCookies(uri, _cookiesss);

                    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

                    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        _notificationRawText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        Console.WriteLine(_notificationRawText);
                        _rawNoteText = _notificationRawText;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                _notificationHttpRequestInProgress = false;
            });

        }
```

This returns, but not the authenticated webtext request; I get the same response any user would get on a browser having never logged in.  If I were to browse out to this same url on any `WebView` in my app, I'd get a completely different response.

You will also notice some commented out code that was another failed attempt at adding the cookies into a connection.  I had also tried using `HttpURLConnection.SetRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);`

where cookies was a `CookieCollection` and that didn't work either.  The code is mostly commented out and layered because I've been trying this for days.

Does anyone know how I can pass `WebView` cookies into an `HttpRequest` using Xamarin.Android?

I am putting this code below in `Fragment5` of my app; you can see and compile the full context here:

https://github.com/hexag0d/BitChute_Mobile_Android_BottomNav/blob/NotificationAdder/Fragments/TheFragment5.cs

Comment: ,If you want to get cookie from webview and set in httpclient, I suggest you can take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798500/android-sync-cookies-webview-and-httpclient

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.  It might have something to do with the fact that Xamarin.Android doesn't have a `CookieStore`?  Thanks for the response tho!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly why the above example didn't work; maybe if you're better at .NET than I am, you could figure it out.  However, I was able to successfully pass `WebView` creds into an `HttpClient` by following these steps, which are returning an authenticated response.  This may not be the most elegant way of doing it, but you can always refine my answer, or post a better one.

What I had to do was set the `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders` using the `.Add()` method like this: `_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", TheFragment5._cookieHeader);`

I got the CookieHeader (which is just a `string` btw) like this:

```
//instantiate a string that will house our cookie header

public static string _cookieHeader;

//you might want to make it private to prevent abuse
//but this example is just for demonstration
//the thing is we need a string to house our headers in scope of both the WebView and the HttpClient

//extend the WebViewClient
        private class ExtWebViewClient : WebViewClient
        {
            public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
            {
            //I get the cookies when the page finishes loading because
            //then we know the cookie has our login cred header
            //also, most of the previous examples got the cookies OnPageFinished

            TheFragment5._cookieHeader = Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.GetCookie(url);

            }
        }
```

Then we need another method for the `HttpClient` and `HttpClientHandler` ... mine scans a webpage for notification text.

```
            public async void GetNotificationText(string url)
            {
                await Task.Run(() =>
                {
                   /* this line is pretty important, 
                    we need to instantiate an HttpClientHandler 
                    then set it's UseCookies property to false
                    so that it doesn't override our cookies
                  */
                    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseCookies = false };

                    try
                    {
                        Uri _notificationURI = new Uri("https://bitchute.com/notifications/");

                        //instantiate HttpClient using the handler
                        using (HttpClient _client = new HttpClient(handler))
                        {
                         //this line is where the magic happens; 
                         //we set the DefaultRequestHeaders with the cookieheader we got from WebViewClient.OnPageFinished                
                         _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", TheFragment5._cookieHeader);

                            //do a GetAsync request with our cookied up client
                            var getRequest = _client.GetAsync("https://bitchute.com/notifications/").Result;

                            //resultContent is the authenticated html string response from the server, ready to be parsed =]
                            var resultContent = getRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                            /*
                            I was writing to console to check the                
                            response.. for me, I am now getting  
                            the authenticated notification html 
                            page
                            */
                            Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }   
                }
            }
```

Hope this helps you, posting for future reference, especially for people using Xamarin.Android.